# Best way to get Turtlebot's current velocity?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

What's the best way to get the current velocity of the turtlebot?

I saw that I could listen to the Odom messages directly, or ask tf to getTwist().  Which method will give me the most accurate estimate?  Or is there another way that's better?

**Update**

I'm doing SLAM on a known map, so I have localization information.

**What I ended up doing**

Here's what I ended up doing after some trial and error.  This example is using the tf_tutorials, but the real robot is similar.  Just change "turtle" to "base_link" and "world" to "map".  "lin" has the linear acceleration and "ang" has the angular.  The velocity is relative to the world frame.

```
(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/world', turtle, rospy.Time(0.0))
(lin, ang) = listener.lookupTwistFull(turtle, '/world', turtle, (0,0,0), '/world', rospy.Time(0.0), rospy.Duration(0.1))
```

Thanks in advance,
-Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39303/best-way-to-get-turtlebot%27s-current-velocity?/) by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Supposing that you are trying to perform SLAM, turtlebot publishes odom data but robot_pose_ekf sends the transform ( as odom_combined i think) which is the filtered version. I think that it is better for you to subscribe topics which robot_pose_ekf puslishes

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-07-19**:
As far as I can tell, robot_pose_ekf just publishes a geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, which doesn't include velocity.  Am I missing something?

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-07-19**:
dx/dt = v will give you the velocity i guess

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-07-19**:
I think tf's getTwist() does that for you and the ekf_robot_pose publishes an odom frame... so it's sounding like that's the way to do it.  I was just wondering if there's a more direct way.  Thanks for responding.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-19**:
The odom topic published by turtlebot will give the instantaneous velocity as calculated by the wheel encoders. The pose topic published by robot_pose_ekf is a filtered result from all odometry inputs, so differentiating that over time will give a "filtered" (close to instantaneous) velocity value.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-19**:
and if you use the localization value (/map->/base_link transform) and differentiate that, it would probably be an average velocity since the localization may have discrete jumps